# What's the difference between Findbugs-IDEA plugin and QAPlug - Findbugs plugin in IntellijJ IDEA

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, findbugs

When I browse repos on intellij plugins, I see

- FindBugs - IDEA plugin
- QAPlug - Findbugs plugin

For now I installed QAPlug, since it integrates with PMD, Checkstyle etc. But I was curious to know what's the differences between those two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A website I found helpful is https://code.google.com/p/findbugs/wiki/IntellijFindBugsPlugins. It has a graph showing the difference between the three findbugs plugins that are commonly found in IntelliJ IDEA and walks the reader through some settings of each of them.

Comment: That table was EXACTlY what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Happy I could help, even though it was almost a year after you asked.

Answer (score 4):

[Findbugs-IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3847?pr=idea) seems to have a lot more features than [QAPlugs - Findbugs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4597?pr=idea).  One such feature is background scanning, which I find very helpful.